# Fliter JSON Map Data using ID in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm struggling to understand how I can filter data by ID using providers. The approach I have tried yields the below error:

```
Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' has no instance getter 'id'.
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:8
Tried calling: id
```

Given my little experience in Flutter, any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.
The code I have written is below:

```
class PopularDishesProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final Map<String, dynamic> _popularDishes = {       //This is the JSON map that I would like to filter from
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Chicken Tandoor Combo",
        "restaurantName": "Tandoori House",
        "price": "455",
        "rating": "4.3",
        "totalRatings": "154",
        "image": "assets/images/Rectangle 17323.png",
        "isFavourite": false
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Pan Cake",
        "restaurantName": "The Pancake Centre",
        "price": "250",
        "rating": "4.7",
        "totalRatings": "256",
        "image": "assets/images/Rectangle 17324.png",
        "isFavourite": false
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Salad",
        "restaurantName": "The Pancake House",
        "price": "180",
        "rating": "4.1",
        "totalRatings": "203",
        "image": "assets/images/Rectangle 17325.png",
        "isFavourite": false
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Roast Chicken",
        "restaurantName": "Kentucky\"s Fried Chicken",
        "price": "550",
        "rating": "4.8",
        "totalRatings": "1000",
        "image": "assets/images/Rectangle 17323 (2).png",
        "isFavourite": false
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Ice Cream",
        "restaurantName": "Naturals",
        "price": "80",
        "rating": "5.0",
        "totalRatings": "1500",
        "image": "assets/images/Rectangle 17324 (2).png",
        "isFavourite": false
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Chicken Tandoor Combo",
        "restaurantName": "Tandoori House",
        "price": "455",
        "rating": "4.3",
        "totalRatings": "154",
        "image": "assets/images/Rectangle 17323.png",
        "isFavourite": false
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Pan Cake",
        "restaurantName": "The Pancake Centre",
        "price": "250",
        "rating": "4.7",
        "totalRatings": "256",
        "image": "assets/images/Rectangle 17324.png",
        "isFavourite": false
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "Salad",
        "restaurantName": "The Pancake House",
        "price": "180",
        "rating": "4.1",
        "totalRatings": "203",
        "image": "assets/images/Rectangle 17325.png",
        "isFavourite": false
      },
      {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Roast Chicken",
        "restaurantName": "Kentucky\"s Fried Chicken",
        "price": "550",
        "rating": "4.8",
        "totalRatings": "1000",
        "image": "assets/images/Rectangle 17323 (2).png",
        "isFavourite": false
      },
      {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Ice Cream",
        "restaurantName": "Naturals",
        "price": "80",
        "rating": "5.0",
        "totalRatings": "1500",
        "image": "assets/images/Rectangle 17324 (2).png",
        "isFavourite": false
      }
    ]
  };

  Map<String, dynamic> get popularDishes {
    return {..._popularDishes};
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> getProductById(String id) {       //The filter method that I've tried to write that yields the error
    return _popularDishes["data"].where((value) => value.id == id).toList();
  }
```

This is how I'm calling the getProductById method using provider.
`routes['id']` is basically the id taken as a route argument from the previous page. The id is derived from the same JSON data that is on this question.

```
class CartScreenState extends State<CartScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final textScale = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor * 1.2;
    final routes =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
    routes['id']   
final id = routes['id'];
    
    final provider =
        Provider.of<PopularDishesProvider>(context).getProductById(id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Map<String, dynamic> getProductById(String id) {       //The filter method that I've tried to write that yields the error
    return _popularDishes["data"].where((value) => value.id == id).toList();
  }
```

First of all, you are accessing id as a getter on the map object so you have to write it like this

```
return _popularDishes["data"].where((value) => value['id'] == id).toList();
```

The second thing is your function return type is `Map<String, dynamic>` but you are returning list as you have used `toList()` so either make your function return type as `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` or if you have to return only first single match then you can use `firstWhere` instead of `where`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be the following:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

Map<String, dynamic>? getProductById(String id) {       
  final dishes = _popularDishes["data"] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
  return dishes.where((dish) => dish["id"] == id).firstOrNull;
}
```

By type casting your dishes list, you can make clear that you are dealing with maps of a certain type (like `Map<String, dynamic>`). That way you can access a certain value by its key using square brackets (`dish["id"]`) and then compare the value to the passed parameter.

Additionally, you tried to return a list (by using the `toList()` method) but your return type was `Map<String, dynamic>`. So if you would like to return a list, you could change the return type to `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`. Otherwise you can use `firstOrNull` (from the collection package) to get your result (or null if nothing was found). For returning null, you must mark the return type nullable.

Hope this solves the problem :)